# Missing badge inbox notifications

Tags: bug

In the last 24 hours I have earned 3 Badges on Android Enthusiasts but I have had not notifications of these badges while I have received others (Answers and Comments). The badges I earned are Supporter, Scholar, and Editor all for my latest question on the site.

Comment: The drop down top bar thingamajig has recently been revamped.  Are you sure you haven't gotten the notification in a different place than you're used to?  It's under the Achievements menu (which looks like a kind of bar graph) rather than the Inbox.

Comment: @MatthewRead I did check there but all it shows is the rep I got from Accepting the answer to the question and the Notable Question badge I got for another question.

Comment: Looks like what ever the issue was it might be fixed now as I just got a notification of getting a badge for the last question I asked on the site.